# Hi about wordpress require_once

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to seperate my files and organize it by not putting them in the function.php I did this.

```html
function required_theme_files() {
 require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/customize/color.php' );
 require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/sidebar.php' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'required_theme_files' );
```

but the sidebar.php doesn't work at all can't seem to know the problem I'm not really a programmer more of a front end designer.

```html
function ounox_widget_setup() {
   
 register_sidebar(
  array(
   'name' => 'Sidebar',
   'id' => 'sidebar-1',
   'class' => 'custom',
   'description' => 'Standard Sidebar',
   'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
   'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
   'before_title'  => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
   'after_title'   => '</h6>',
  )
 );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init','ounox_widget_setup' );
```

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Debug and see what PHP errors you are getting, such as `sidebar.php` not being loaded or found.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Change the "display" line to true

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to dump them to the browser as well as log them.

1) Do you have the opening `<?php` at the top of `sidebar.php`?

2) Or, your issue may be the use of `get_template_directory`. That returns an absolute server path (eg: /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme), not a URI.

In the case of a child theme being used, the absolute path to the parent theme directory will be returned. Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the absolute path to the child theme directory. See [get_stylesheet_directory_uri() | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)